# "TypeError: a is null" in Google maps API when clicking back

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I get a "TypeError: a is null" and a blank map in Google maps API when clicking back:

```
14:27:57.271 TypeError: a is null
_.Uf()js:82
Dg()js:90
initMap()map.php:36
Zg/<()js:96
lc/e<()js:49
_.ac()js:46
lc()js:49
<anonymous>js:130
google.maps.Load()js:21
<anonymous>js:130
<anonymous>js:26
1js:82:453
```

In the header section I use:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.25&
key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyy&callback=initMap" async="" 
defer=""></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        var center = {
            lat: 51.46606900136,
            lng: -2.5865578706776
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: center,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center,
            icon: "icon.png",
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
```

The body section has the map element:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

The map displays OK the first time.  The problem only seems to occur when clicking back, so I'm guessing that I need to somehow force the Javascript to execute again if the page is reloaded in this way.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that when you navigate back to your map, the `<div id=map></div>` hasn't rendered before the `initMap` function is called.  To fix that put the code in the body after the `<div id="map"></map>`:

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    var center = {
      lat: 51.46606900136,
      lng: -2.5865578706776
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: center,
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      // icon: "icon.png",
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have fixed the problem. I'll accept your answer soon.  Why did you comment out the "icon" code?

Comment: That doesn't exist on SO (or anywhere else for me, it is local to your website), and wasn't relevant to your issue.